# $\text{SO}(4)$ is homeomorphic to $\text{SO}(3)\times S^3$

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, lie-groups, fiber-bundles

Is there a reference for a proof that $\text{SO}(4)$ is homeomorphic to $\text{SO}(3)\times S^3$? Since $\text{SO}(4)$ acts transitively on $S^3$ with stabilizer $\text{SO}(3)$, we have a fiber bundle $\text{SO}(3)\to \text{SO}(4)\to S^3$, but I can't see why this bundle is trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a reference about the topology of SO(4):

http://www.gregegan.net/ORTHOGONAL/03/WavesExtra.html#topology

You can also see this article of wikipedia:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_in_4-dimensional_Euclidean_space#Group_structure_of_SO(4)

Which describes precisely the universal cover of SO(4).